# PromQL: What is rate() function meant for?

Tags: prometheus, promql, micrometer

I have a question regarding PromQL and its query functions rate() and how to use it properly. In my application, I have a thread running, and I use Micrometer's Timer to monitor the thread's runtime. Using Timer gives you a counter with suffix _count and another counter with the sum of the seconds spent with suffix _sum. E.g. my_metric_sum and my_metric_count.

My raw data looks like this (scrape interval 30 s, range vector 5m):

[image]

Now according to the docs, https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate *calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector* (which is 5m here).

Now my question is: why would I want that? The relative change of my execution runtime seems pretty useless to me. In fact, just using sum/count looks more useful as it gives me the avg absolute duration for each moment in time. At the same time, and this is what confused me, in the docs I find

To calculate the average request duration during the last 5 minutes from a histogram or summary called http_request_duration_seconds, use the following expression:

rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m]) / rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])

Source: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/

But as I understand the docs, it looks like this expression would calculate the per-second average rate of increase of the request duration, ie not how long a request takes on average, but instead how much the request duration has changed on average in the last 5 minutes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `rate(m[d])` function calculates the increase of a [counter metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) `m` over the given lookbehind window `d` in square brackets and then divides the increase by `d`. The calculation is performed independently per each matching time series `m`. For example, suppose there are `http_requests_total` metrics with `url` label:

```
http_requests_total{url="/foo"}
http_requests_total{url="/bar"}
```

If they have the following values at time `t0`:

```
http_requests_total{url="/foo"} 123
http_requests_total{url="/bar"} 456
```

... and the following values at time `t0 + 5 minutes`:

```
http_requests_total{url="/foo"} 345
http_requests_total{url="/bar"} 789
```

Then `rate(http_requests_total[5m])` at time `t0 + 5 minutes` is calculated in the following way:

1. To calculate [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) for these metrics between `t0` and `t0 + 5 minutes`:

```
increase(http_requests_total{url="/foo"}[5m]) = 345 - 123 = 222
increase(http_requests_total{url="/bar"}[5m]) = 789 - 456 = 333
```

2. To divide the calculated increase by `5 minutes` expressed in seconds (`5*60s = 300s`):

```
rate(http_requests_total{url="/foo"}[5m]) = 222 / 300 = 0.74
rate(http_requests_total{url="/bar"}[5m]) = 333 / 300 = 1.11
```

So the end result of `rate(http_requests_total[5m])` is a per-second average rps for the last 5 minutes, which is calculated individually per each time series with `http_requests_total` name.

A few notes:

- Both [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) and [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) properly handle e.g. `counter resets`, when the [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) is reset to zero.
- Sometimes Prometheus can return unexpected results from `rate()` and `increase()` because of the chosen data model. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). This issue is addressed in VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on - see [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e).
- Some PromQL-compatible query engines such as [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) allow skipping the lookbehind window in square brackets when using `rate()` function, so `rate(http_requests_total)` is a valid MetricsQL query. In this case it automatically adds `[$__interval]` lookbehind window before query execution. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions) for more details.

Comment: This answer is much better than the one that is currently checked green, but again I don't understand how it answers original question, which is - we are interested in the average time that requests in the given window took, not the increase rate or whatever. Can you explain why we should be concerned with increase rate instead?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012736/274937

Answer (score 2):

While I am not familiar with Micrometer Timer, the metric you're describing is of type Summary. It is counting the "events" in `_count` and summing the events magnitude, like duration, elapsed time and similar, in `_sum`.
If you now perform `rate(metric_count[5m])`, you'll get the 5m average per second rate of your events. And if you want to know the average duration of these events within 5m window, you do
`rate(metric_sum[5m]) / rate(metric_count[5m])`. If you try dividing `metric_sum/metric_count`, you'll get all time (since counter reset) average instead of 5m average at some point in time.
In a way, it looks a bit funny to use `rate()` for this. Using `increase()` seems more intuitive to me, but mathematically it's exactly the same as `rate()` is just an `increase()/range` and so these ranges cancel each other out in `rate(metric_sum[5m]) / rate(metric_count[5m])`.

Comment: I do not get how this answers the original question. Do you say that `rate` in Prometheus is the average and that it is called `rate` only because `avg` is reserved for a different purpose?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - use the tool that matches your use case.

Second - whatever you choose, **validate** the data. And better do it now than during an outage or with an angry customer/user.

Third - `_count` and `_bucket` are features of **histograms** and **summaries**. The sampling frequency doesn't really matter here, as long as it's smaller than the `[5m]` grouping of the `rate()` function.

The rate simply gives you data points of "how many occurrences happened during these five minutes (`[5m]`).

General note - the `rate()` concept in Prometheus is causing a lot of confusion. It's debated between too many people. They should have probably called it something else.