# How can rate() function average request duration?

Tags: prometheus, promql

Quote from Prometheus [Count and sum of observations](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#count-and-sum-of-observations) doc:

> To calculate the average request duration during the last 5 minutes from a histogram or summary called http_request_duration_seconds, use the following expression:
> `rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m]) / rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])`

I should mention that I understand:

1. what `rate` function does
2. how instant vector is different from range vector
3. that if I wanted to obtain average request duration increase rate I would definitely use that expression

However I'm not interested in the increase rate of request duration, but rather in the request duration itself!

Can someone explain why everybody while looking for average count/value in any given moment of time has to use a `rate` function, when it doesn't provide that?

P.S. there's seemingly a [duplicate question with a checked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400298/promql-what-is-rate-function-meant-for), however all answers in it explain what `rate` function is, how it does what it does, etc. I already understand what `rate` function does. I just don't understand why we are supposed to use it in first place, especially when the result that it provides has nothing to do with what we're looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's show that the formula quoted from the Prometheus manual, making use of the function named `rate()`, computes the exact value you are looking for.

According to the way a counter works, we know that each time the counter named `http_request_duration_seconds_sum` takes into account a new value, that is the sum of durations of all the requests that happened from the last time, it adds this sum to its previous value.
Therefore, `rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])` is the sum of the durations of the requests that occurred during 5 minutes, divided by 5 minutes.

And each time the counter `http_request_duration_seconds_count` takes into account a new value, that is the number of requests that happened from the last time, this counter adds this number of requests to its previous value.
Therefore, `rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])` is the number of requests that occurred during 5 minutes, divided by 5 minutes.

So, let's inject the formulas discovered in the two previous paragraphs into the following fraction:

[image: rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])/rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])]

equals to:

[image: ((sum of the durations of the requests that occurred during 5 minutes) / 5 minutes) / ((number of requests that occurred during 5 minutes) / 5 minutes)]

You can simplify this formula by removing `5 minutes`, because it is present in the numerator and in the denominator.

Finally, the following formula:

[image: rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])/rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])]

is equal to the following one:

[image: (sum of the durations of the requests that occurred during 5 minutes)/(number of requests that occurred during 5 minutes)]

The second part of this equality is the value you want to compute: the average duration of requests during 5 minutes. This is why it is computed using the first part of this equality.

Answer (score 5):

Prometheus [summary](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary) and [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) metric types expose two additional counters:

- The total count of the particular measurements since the service start. This counter is constructed by adding `_count` suffix to the original metric name. For example, if the original `historgam` or `summary` metric name is `http_request_duration_seconds` (see [docs for metric naming convention in Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#metric-names)), then the the `http_request_duration_seconds_count` counter is generated, which counts **the total number of http requests since the service start**.
- The total sum of all the measurements since the service start. This metric is constructed by adding `_sum` suffix to the original metric name. For example, if the original metric name is `http_request_duration_seconds`, then the `http_request_duration_seconds_sum` counter contains the **total sum of all the http request durations since the service start**.

How to calculate the average request duration from these two metrics? An obvious solution is to divide sum of all the request durations by the number of requests:

```
http_request_duration_seconds_sum / http_request_duration_seconds_total
```

But this solution shows the average request duration **since the last restart of the service**. Usually users are interested in an average request duration over some lookbehind interval. For example, over the last 5 minutes. Then we need do divide the sum of all the request durations during the last 5 minutes by the number of requests served during the last 5 minutes. This can be done with [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function:

```
increase(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])
  /
increase(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])
```

The [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function in Prometheus is calculated as `rate(m[d]) = increase(m[d])/d`, e.g. this is `increase()` divided by the lookbehind window `d`. Let's substitute `increase` with `rate` in the query above:

```
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])
  /
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])
```

Now let's substitute `rate(m[d])` with `increase(m[d])/d` according to the formula above:

```
(increase(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])/5m)
  /
(increase(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])/5m)
```

The `5m` denominators can be collapsed, so we end up with the initial query with `increase()`. So it is OK to use either `rate` or `increase` in the query above - this shouldn't change the result.